# How much space does each datatype in R require in memory? Which is the smallest?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I want to keep the size of my dataset to a minimum so I was wondering about the different data types in R and which one requires the least space.

Specifically if I have an integer (e.g. 1) vs a character (e.g. "a") which requires less space to store?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try this: `lobstr::obj_size(1L)` will return 56B, l`obstr::obj_size("a")` will return 112B.

Comment: One good reference is http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the `dplyr` and `data.table` packages specifically, why did you add the [tag:dplyr] and [tag:data.table] tags? If you are profiling frames stored in both, and you are short on memory (can't afford to copy it frequently), then almost certainly `data.table` is your answer.